# Rule of thumb for relative current capacity of conductors

Tags: current

Is there a "rule of thumb" for the relative current capacity of wire (other factors such as temperature, allowable voltage drop, distance, insulation, etc. being equal).

For instance:

- Decreasing AWG by X increases current capacity by Y
- Increasing AWG by X decreases current capacity by Y

Comment: Any "rule of thumb" is superceded by the relevant regulations in force in your area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very general terms, **decreasing AWG by 2 gauges gives 60% more current.**

Under no circumstances finalise a design based on this; it's just for getting an intuitive understanding.  Always check with proper rules for real designs.

[image]
*NFPA 70 values via [Wikipedia AWG page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Tables_of_AWG_wire_sizes)*

Comment: But that's literally the same as saying it allows +26% per 1 AWG step, or that it doubles per 3 AWG steps? Which actually comes from the definition of AWG, as the wire area and thus resistance changes by factor of 2 every 3 AWG step.

Comment: @justme thanks for your comment.  Of course it's the same; I expressed it in steps of 2 because a lot of wire is sold in even gauges.  I think "60% per step" is an easy generalisation to understand and remember, which is what I thought the OP was after.  "Doubles for 3AWG step" is also useful, just harder to use.

Comment: Yeah they both are really the same rule of thumb or definition expressed in different units and I guess the "harder to use" depends on context. Just like 2nd order filters can be expressed to have a slope of 40dB per decade or 12dB per octave, which is the same expressed in different units.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand two things.

First thing is how the AWG actually affecs the wire, which comes from the definition of AWG, so it is not even a rule of thumb, just simple math, and has nothing to do with practical use of the cable.

The second thing is, the current rating depends on the safety and environment the wire is used in and how it is installed and what it needs to handle.

When AWG increases or decreases by 3, it halves or doubles the wire area, which again doubles or halves the wire resistance per unit of length. So by definition, increasing the AWG by 6 means half the current will cause equal power loss in the wire, so all things being equal the ampacity is halved if power loss in the wire is kept constant.

But there are other factors that affect how much margin you need for safety in instaces such as overload or short circuit. As the power lost in the wire is proportional to the current squared, and temperature rise is proportional to power and time, it really means that e.g. how fast a fuse acts defines the difference between wire just warming up slightly or getting vapourized in a flash.

So the ampacity vs AWG is dependend on where, when and how, in which environment you are using the wire, and how much the wire temperature is allowed to rise during normal use, slight overload, or gross overload conditions and time. And it also depends what safety or electricty codes require depending on what kind of device it is. There is no rule of thumb to cover all scenarios. You may need to rate the AWG for practical safety reasons, such as due to motor or power supply taking a large startup or inrush current even if the current under normal use is not that large.

One example is that you have a single wire in open space, or a bundle of 100 wires packed tightly in an enclosed space with no ventilation. In this case, electrical codes and safety rules define the AWG vs ampacity for the single wire.

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors involved, most of which have been discussed above. The most generally used is the fusing current, which is based on I^ * t. This is usually further specified for the melting point of copper, which is the most common material for general purpose conductors. I have constructed a wire size chart (in Excel and Open Office) which also includes various shapes and sizes of copper bus bars as used in many of the devices I have worked on (1000 to 100,000 amps). In the columns I have also included various recommended and minimum AWG for current, including the usual NFP code sizes, transformer wiring sizes, and basic amps per circular mils.

[image: Wire size chart]

Answer (score 0):

There's a critical factor everyone thusfar has missed.  You can't simply note a temprature rise in a wire and declare victory.   You must account for how the heat escapes the wire.

And this is where the square-cube law pinches you hard - if you double the diameter and thus quadruple the cross-section of a wire, you have quartered its resistance, true - **but you have only doubled its surface area**.

And the surface area is the medium by which heat escapes.

That is why, when you look through the ampacity tables such as NEC 310.15(B)(16), doubling wire diameter / quadrupling cross-section only provides a 2 to 2.75 times increase in allowable current at a temperature.

And this is why "paralleling" is so valuable. Provided you provide enough separation for cooling, 4 parallels of a wire really is 4 times the current.

Comment: My chart has one column that accounts for surface area, which may apply to radiated and convection cooling. But there is also thermal conduction through connectors and mechanical components. This is also taken into account when specifying wire sizes and clamps in fuses and circuit breakers,